# Qt. Redefine QString::compare in heavy applications

Tags: qt, sorting

My task is custom sorting items in QStandardItemModel. 
By default for a sequance of rows

```
 text1
 text11
 text12
 text100
 text110
 text120
 text1110
```

function `QStandardItemModel::sort()` sorting it as

```
 text1
 text100
 text11
 text110
 text1110
 text12
 text120
```

I want that would be

```
 text1
 text11
 text12
 text100
 text110
 text120
 text1110
```

For this purpose I overload function `int QString::compare(const QString &s) const`  in the separeted  `compare.cpp`  file.

```
   int QString::compare(const QString &s) const
   {
       QString strL = "";
       strL.append(this);
       QString strR = "";
       strR.append(s);

       QStringList list = strL.split(QRegExp("\\D+"),QString::SkipEmptyParts);
       foreach (QString num, list) {
           strL.replace(num, QString("%1").arg(num,10,'0'));
       }

       list = strR.split(QRegExp("\\D+"),QString::SkipEmptyParts);
       foreach (QString num, list) {
           strR.replace(num, QString("%1").arg(num,10,'0'));
       }

       return strL.localeAwareCompare(strR);
   }
```

that using in operator 
`virtual bool  operator< ( const QStandardItem & other ) const`.

Such function as `compare` can be redefined in the separate file and it is simple to add it in *.pro and easy application will find its realization. But with more difficult applications such way it is impossible. Please tell me Why?

Example : [code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pdf0q8tzzc0yw1k/CustomSorting.tbz2)

Comment: Can you show me standard definition that allows such construction?

Comment: I didn't understand that you want to see. Сan be this  
[source](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pdf0q8tzzc0yw1k/CustomSorting.tbz2) will help? It's small example of use.

Comment: what is your question? what is an easy application and a difficult one?

Comment: @SashaMirko I'm just trying to point you out that you shouldn't "redefine" existing methods. Also "redefining" method for base class like QString will affect your whole application. It's bad approach. Thats it. Also I'm not sure about that but you're not allowed to do such thing, as linker will complain about double definition of same member

Comment: I did! =D All problems was in links. Look the description below.

Comment: @Kamil Klimek Yes. you are right. linker was complaining about double definition of same, but I solved this problem having wrapped up a method in library. Look the description below

Comment: I don't know how to say it again. DON'T DO THIS! IT'S EVIL! But seriously. You're doing something reeeaaaalyyyy stupid. Thats all.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using a `QStandardItemModel` directly, you want to wrap it in a `QSortFilterProxyModel`. This class was designed for exactly the situation you describe--when you want to implement custom sorting or filtering behavior. Just implement the `QSortFilterProxyModel::lessThan` method to reflect the desired behavior.

Comment: Thank you, I know, but me interests other decision and I  found it

Answer (score 0):

`QStandardItemModel` has a virtual function `sort(int column, Qt::SortOrder order = Qt::AscendingOrder)`. I think it will be easier to subclass `QStandardItemModel` and reimplement `sort`function.

Comment: I agree. It is so possible to make. But it is interesting to use option without inheritance. Because eventually according to source codes of Qt the function QStandardItemModel::sort call the QString function::compare

Answer (score -2):

I did!

When i said "heavy application", i means application, that contains and binds  many other plugins and libs. And for this purpose what I create the new lib with name QStringCompare, that contains one file compare.cpp with my new definiotoin of compare:

```
#include <QStringList>
#include <QRegExp>
int Q_DECL_EXPORT QString::compare(const QString &s) const
{
    QString strL = "";
    strL.append(this);
    QString strR = "";
    strR.append(s);

    QStringList list = strL.split(QRegExp("\\D+"),QString::SkipEmptyParts);
    foreach (QString num, list) {
        strL.replace(num, QString("%1").arg(num,10,'0'));
    }

    list = strR.split(QRegExp("\\D+"),QString::SkipEmptyParts);
    foreach (QString num, list) {
        strR.replace(num, QString("%1").arg(num,10,'0'));
    }

    return strL.localeAwareCompare(strR);
}
```

and it links QStringCompare.lib to *.pro of Main apllication of my project.  Generally it's not necessary to declare it in *.h files. All other plug-ins inherit this redefinition. The experiments showed that it is necessary to links to main application.
As that so.

There can be I am mistaken in reasonings, but it's working on linux and windows.

This is source of [QStringCompare.libs](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3n7xhz5hkekuxxy/QStringCompare.tbz2). You can try.

Comment: Like Kamil said, this is *not* a good idea. I am not sure if the behavior you are seeing now is anything guaranteed by the spec, or just fortuitous, but in any case it is very fragile to define the same method in multiple libraries and trust the linker to choose the right one to "win" the collision.